# How to chain two Ansible module in one task

Tags: ansible

There is something I need to achieve in Ansible that I found no where to start.

I need to

1. Login as a **non-root user** (**remote_user**: jane)
2. Switch user to root after login (This user cannot login from SSH)
3. Then switch to another user(**nginx_user**) from **root** to avoid password
4. Execute a custom command using **command** module in Ansible

The reason that I have step2 and step3 is  because if I switch from **jane** to **nginx_user**, the system will ask for password. While if I switch from root, then no password input is needed. The other fact is **nginx_user** has no password, if you just press enter while the system ask for password, it will fail to authenticate.

I started something like this, assume **remote_user** is set to **jane**.

```
- name: Task name
  sudo_user: root
  sudo: yes
  # Need to switch to **nginx_user** before executing this command below
  command: cp /var/www/a /var/www/b
```

The problem is, after the account is switched to root, I need to change the user to **nginx_user** before I can execute the command, is there a way to do this in Ansible?

#### Update:

The **command** module is just an example, I may need to use other module in my case instead, but it would require you to switch to **nginx_user** first, so I couldn't hack in the bash command.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about the problem rather than the attempted solution, things will become clear.

[see 'the xy problem'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (meta.stackexchange link).

From your attempt, it seems you want to copy `/var/www/a` to `/var/www/b` using `nginx` instead of your ansible_user.  I assume because you want to preserve ownership and permissions.

Fortunately, Ansible has an idempotent module which will do what you need.

```yaml
- name: Copy 'a' to 'b'
  become: yes
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src:  '/var/www/a'
    dest: '/var/www/b'
    owner: nginx
    group: nginx
    mode: '0644' # or whatever you want, 
                 # but security best practice 
                 # makes this the max for a file
    backup: no   # change to yes if you need to
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html

Answer (score -1):

The usual aproach to this task is following:

Your remote user (I'd recommend an extra user solely for ansible tasks) should have passwordless sudo:

```
jane ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Keep your task as is, with sudo_user: nginx_user.

```
- name: Task name
  sudo_user: nginx_user
  sudo: yes
  command: cp /var/www/a /var/www/b
```

Ansible does something like `sudo su nginx_user` in that case, and as your remote user has passwordless sudo, no password is required.